# Trouble requiring too many images in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have javascript file that looks like below. It has lots of object (1000+). As we cannot use dynamic name for images in react-native this is my work around.

```
"grinning": {
        "image": require('./images/1f600.png'),
        "shortname": ":grinning:",
    }
```

I am requiring this file in some other react native function and looping to display all the images. But getting internal error on requiring too many images in javascript file.

```
{"type":"InternalError","message":"react-packager has encountered an internal error, please check your terminal error output for details"}
```

In terminal it says

```
fs operation timeout
```

This works if i remove few entries from the file.

Any suggestion or better approach

Comment: try to call require without . and put absolut path like "/mypictures/another/folder/my.png". Do you want the picture file or juste the path into "image" key ? if you juste want the path you should not use require

Comment: why are you using require on an image file ? require should normally be used to wait the loading of a file before start loading the rest. If you place it in a loop it will take a long long time and if it's too long according to your settings you can have a timeout. Why do you not only put the path in your json object ? how are you displaying your image ?

Comment: I am using require because you cannot have dynamic name for images in react-native. You have to specify everything at runtime so it can bundle up everything before loading the app.

Answer (score 2):

There are [known issues](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.28/docs/known-issues.html#memory-issues-with-png-images) with the Fresco library in charge of handling images, and memory limits:

> **Memory issues with PNG images**
>
> React Native Android depends on Fresco
> for loading and displaying images. Currently we have disabled
> downsampling because it is experimental, so you may run into memory
> issues when loading large PNG images.

So maybe try compressing your images if you can, and only require them when they have to be rendered.

You should also check the [bug tracker](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20fresco). Here is a [comparable issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6649#issuecomment-226961561) and its fix:

> **@phones24 wrote:**
>
> I optimized my app so it's not cached too many images. I also added
> some more JPEG compression and scale the images down a bit. I also
> wrote a path that adds error information to the event.

Comment: i can not required them when i need to render because its a huge file and i will have to copy that code every where. And its not just android issue but iOS specific